# Rails 5 Seclect2 Acts_as_taggable Populates tag name on first product then sets the id as the name on all other products

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, acts-as-taggable-on

So I'm building a Rails 5 app using Select2-rails and acts_as_taggable gems.

The selcet2 box is working fine and creates the tags as it should, but only when it's a new tag being made.

Any tag selected after the initial tag is created, is duplicated but saved with the id as the tag name and a new id assigned to it. I have no idea why this is happening!

**Initial Product Created with associated Tags:**
[image]

**2nd Product created but saves tag id's as the tag name and assigns new ID**
[image]

**my Select2 Js:**

```
// JS Initializer
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // Select2 Tag Creation
  $('.multiple-input').each(function() {
    $(this).select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeperators: [','],
      theme: 'bootstrap',
      placeholder: 'seperated by space',
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      ajax: {
        url: "/tags.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          return {results: data};
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

**My tags controller thats populating the /tags.json**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
      .where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
      .select("id, name as text")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: tags}
    end
  end

end
```

**Stack Trace where Tags are created properly:**

```
Started POST "/products" for ::1 at 2019-04-21 11:34:18 -0600
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SPc9Ri+RK6yIm19Six5EGhUBPez/IyV7rccKlBcUcR16pNzAFCagEfEg6YelehK2Bk/wlzC54ziWayJyHDqjdQ==", "product"=>{"name"=>"T-Shirt", "description"=>"Test Shirt", "price"=>"19.99", "tag_list"=>["", "T-Shirt", "Mens", "Womens"]}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  Product Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("name", "description", "price", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "T-Shirt"], ["description", "Test Shirt"], ["price", "19.99"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:34:18.330742"], ["updated_at", "2019-04-21 17:34:18.330742"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('t-shirt') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('mens') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('womens'))
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "T-Shirt"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "T-Shirt"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('t-shirt') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('mens') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('womens'))
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Mens"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Mens"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('t-shirt') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('mens') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('womens'))
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Womens"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Womens"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 1], ["taggable_type", "Product"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = $3 AND "taggings"."context" = $4 AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL LIMIT $5  [["tag_id", 1], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 1], ["context", "tags"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "taggable_type", "taggable_id", "context", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 1], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 1], ["context", "tags"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:34:18.422464"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Update All (0.4ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = $3 AND "taggings"."context" = $4 AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL LIMIT $5  [["tag_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 1], ["context", "tags"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "taggable_type", "taggable_id", "context", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 1], ["context", "tags"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:34:18.428044"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Update All (0.3ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = $1  [["id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = $3 AND "taggings"."context" = $4 AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL LIMIT $5  [["tag_id", 3], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 1], ["context", "tags"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "taggable_type", "taggable_id", "context", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 3], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 1], ["context", "tags"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:34:18.432148"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Update All (0.3ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = $1  [["id", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
   (40.8ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/1
Completed 302 Found in 149ms (ActiveRecord: 53.2ms)
```

**Stack Trace where Tags are created improperly**

```
Started POST "/products" for ::1 at 2019-04-21 11:36:37 -0600
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ec/uY1MZ4g4dQmpzp2Uu03VgvRJrjDQB7e/H3ohAjstLnA/laK5ps2T53KaJAXh/Zi5waaQW8kLWQ+84g25cow==", "product"=>{"name"=>"TEST 2", "description"=>"another test with messed up tags", "price"=>"19.99", "tag_list"=>["", "1", "2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  Product Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("name", "description", "price", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "TEST 2"], ["description", "another test with messed up tags"], ["price", "19.99"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:36:37.941777"], ["updated_at", "2019-04-21 17:36:37.941777"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('1') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('2') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('3'))
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "1"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('1') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('2') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('3'))
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "2"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (LOWER(name) = LOWER('1') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('2') OR LOWER(name) = LOWER('3'))
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "3"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "tags" ("name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "3"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 2], ["taggable_type", "Product"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = $3 AND "taggings"."context" = $4 AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL LIMIT $5  [["tag_id", 4], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 2], ["context", "tags"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "taggable_type", "taggable_id", "context", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 4], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 2], ["context", "tags"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:36:37.955779"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Update All (0.3ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = $1  [["id", 4]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = $3 AND "taggings"."context" = $4 AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL LIMIT $5  [["tag_id", 5], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 2], ["context", "tags"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "taggable_type", "taggable_id", "context", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 5], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 2], ["context", "tags"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:36:37.960667"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Update All (0.4ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = $1  [["id", 5]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."tag_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."taggable_id" = $3 AND "taggings"."context" = $4 AND "taggings"."tagger_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."tagger_type" IS NULL LIMIT $5  [["tag_id", 6], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 2], ["context", "tags"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "taggings" ("tag_id", "taggable_type", "taggable_id", "context", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["tag_id", 6], ["taggable_type", "Product"], ["taggable_id", 2], ["context", "tags"], ["created_at", "2019-04-21 17:36:37.966087"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Update All (0.3ms)  UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = COALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = $1  [["id", 6]]
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/2
Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 9.9ms)
```

**Products Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

  def show

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.valid?

        @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, flash: { success: "#{@product.name.titleize} has been created & added to the store." } }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def tagged
    if params[:tag].present?
      @products = Product.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @products = Product.all
    end
  end

  private

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image, :tag_list, tag_list: [])
    end

end
```

Comment: When you create the product what params you see in the log?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I have added the stack trace of a properly and not properly created tag list

Comment: Ok, now could you also share the posts controller create action?

Comment: @ArupRakshit added

Comment: Ok can you add the log now when you create product with new tags?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thats the stack trace at the top or do you want me to do a mix of existing and new?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192179/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-shawn-wilson).